# DRY and Elegant way to represent all search combinations without growing exponentially?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I can search the following

1) leaving_from location

2) going_to location

3) leaving_from &
    going_to location

```
if params[:leaving_from].present? && params[:going_to].present?
  @flights = Flight.where(:source => params[:leaving_from]).where(:destination => params[:going_to])      

elsif params[:leaving_from].present?
  @flights = Flight.where(:source => params[:leaving_from])

elsif params[:going_to].present?
  @flights = Flight.where(:destination => params[:going_to])  

end
```

Is there a dry way to represent this code above? Basically its a for search function compromised of 2 drop down search boxes. One for leaving from location and another for going to location. With the option of narrowing it down by both locations or just one location.

It works fine now but it isn't very scalable. If I added more search parameters say price and time, it would grow exponentially in order to be able to represent all the states.

For example if I added price my new combinations would be

1) leaving_from location

2) going_to location

3) leaving_from &
    going_to location

4) price

5) leaving_from location & price

6) going_to location & price

7) leaving_from location & going_to location & price

I need help to figure out a better way to represent this, or else it would make my controller incredibly bloated.

**EDIT FORM CODE --**

```
=form_tag '/flights', :method =>  :get
 %h4
        Leaving From:   
        =select_tag 'leaving_from', content_tag(:option,'select one...',:value=>"")+options_for_select(@flights_source, 'source'),  { :class => 'form-control' }

 %h4
        Going To:
        =select_tag 'going_to', content_tag(:option,'select one...',:value=>"")+options_for_select(@flights_destination, 'destination'), { :class => 'form-control' }
        %h4=submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'btn btn-success btn-md btn-block'
```

Comment: Are you sure it's working?  `elsif params[:leaving_from].present? && params[:going_to].present?` would never be executed in the above code!

Comment: move this to a dedicated class

Comment: The code has been updated so it can make it to the 3rd level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of using `leaving_from` or `going_to` use `source` and `destination`  instead and Move all the required parameters under a `key`, e.g., this solution will work for any no. of keys

```
'required' => { 'source' => value, 'destination' => value, 'price' => value }
```

Now in the controller define this method in private

```
def get_flights(params) 
  possible_combination = [] 
  conditions = {}   
  key_array = params['required'].keys

  1.upto(key_array.length) { |i| possible_combination + key_array.combination(i).to_a }

  possible_combination.reverse.each do |comb|      
    if comb.collect{ |key| params['required'][key].present? }.inject(:&)
      comb.map { |key| conditions[key] = params['required'][key] }
      break
    end
  end

  Flight.where(conditions)
end
```

Call this method from any action

```
@flights = get_flights(params)
```

Hope this works! Its an overall idea to make this thing dynamic, you can refactor the code according to your need!

Comment: For some reason this did not work and I'm not familiar enough with ruby hashs to figure out why, however I did use some of your ideas to create a private method that did work. I posted it below, any feed back would be welcome.

Comment: Please post your form code, you can edit the question and add code there

Answer (score 1):

First things first: your code does not do what you think it does, since there is no way for it to execute the third `if` (every time the third `if` is `true`, the first `if` is as well). On to your question:

```
@flights = Flight
@flights = @flights.where(:source => params[:leaving_from]) if params[:leaving_from].present?
@flights = @flights.where(:destination => params[:going_to]) if params[:going_to].present?
```

Or

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:source] = params[:leaving_from] if params[:leaving_from].present?
conditions[:destination] = params[:going_to] if params[:going_to].present?
@flights = Flight.where(conditions)
```

Comment: Thanks the first solution works but not the second, I'm trying to get the second one working as that would be less database queries, right? And I edited my original code so it would work.

Comment: No, they're equivalent. `where` does not actually invoke the database query, it just builds it; the query is invoked when you say `all`, `first` or similar. I didn't test; can you say *how* the second case fails? Is there an error? It should behave the same, unless I missed something...

Comment: Oh okay perfect, and no, no errors but @flights is not updated, trying to find out more now. I tried  `@conditions = {}
@conditions[source: params[:leaving_from]] if params[:leaving_from].present?
@conditions[destination: params[:going_to]] if params[:going_to].present?
@flights = Flight.where(@conditions)` and debug \@conditions in the view but its an empty array --- {}

Comment: Duh. Due to acute case of stupidity caused by insomnia, I totally flubbed the hash syntax. Please try again.

Comment: Perfect thank you that worked, after being changed to  `conditions[:source]` and `conditions[:destination]`. And don't worry I am having the exact same problem right now, its 3AM and I have to be up in 3.75 hrs. Anyway thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`ransack`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) which adds your rails to search function very easily.

You just write below, if you use `ransack`.

```
# View (Search Form)
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  From: <%= f.text_field :leaving_from_cont %>
  To  : <%= f.text_field :going_to_cont %>
  Price:
  <%= f.text_field :price_gteq %> 〜 <%= f.text_field :price_lteq %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %> 

# Controller
def index
  @q = Flight.ransack(parmas[:q])
  @flights = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

If a user don't input any fields, ransack don't use the non-input fields value. It means don't add `WHERE` conditions in DB.

- *column_name*_cont means contain (Like in DB).
- *column_name*_eq means equal (== in DB).
- *column_name*_gteq means greater than equal (<= in DB).
- *column_name*_lteq means less than equal (>= in DB).
- etc...

Also you can sort the search result easily by using `sort_link` methods of `ransack`.

Please look in [`ransack`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get [@RSB's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28107630/1438508) code to work but I was able to use his example to create a method that did work. I call the below code in my action.

```
@flights = get_flights(search_params)
```

The search_params method is as follows:

```
def search_params
    params.permit(:leaving_from, :going_to)
    params_hash = {'required' => { 'source' => params[:leaving_from], 'destination' => params[:going_to]}}
end
```

And finally the get_flights method is:

```
def get_flights(params) 

    possible_combination = [] 
    conditions = {}
    key_array = params['required'].keys

    possible_combination = (possible_combination + key_array.combination(key_array.length).to_a).flatten

    possible_combination.each do |comb|
        conditions[comb] = params['required'][comb] if params['required'][comb].present?
    end  

    Flight.where(conditions)
end
```

I am still pretty new to ruby and rails so any feedback or suggestions for improvements would be greatly welcome. Thanks!